# Part of Json not sent to API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

I am having a problem sending data to an api, I am building an Array to send it, but at the time of sending no part of that array is being sent. Then I show you what I am sent and the line is not sent.

```
var guardarHC = {};
            guardarHC.Estudio = Number(datosHC['estudio']);
            guardarHC.FechaAtencion = $("#fecha_atencion_historia").val();
            guardarHC.HoraAtencion = $("#hora_atencion_historia").val();
            guardarHC.XmlDatosHC = XmlDatosHC;
            guardarHC.Servicio = Number(datosHC['fuente_servicio']);
            guardarHC.XmlProcedimientos = XmlProcedimientos;
            guardarHC.CausaExterna = Number(datosHC['hc_causaexterna']);
            guardarHC.TipoDiagnostico = Number(datosHC['hc_tipo_diagnostico']);
            guardarHC.Finalidad = Number(datosHC['hc_finalidad']);
            guardarHC.DestinoPcte = Number(datosHC['destinoPcte']);
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoPrincipal = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_principal'];
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoRelacionado1 = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_relacionado1'];
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoRelacionado2 = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_relacionado2'];
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoRelacionado3 = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_relacionado3'];
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoRelacionado4 = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_relacionado4'];
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoRelacionado5 = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_relacionado5'];
            guardarHC.CodDiagnosticoRelacionado6 = datosHC['codigo_diagnostico_relacionado6'];
            guardarHC.GrupoHC = Number(datosHC['paginita']);
            guardarHC.Usuario = <?php echo $_SESSION['id_user_sistema'] ?>;

            var url = "<?php echo $model->getParametroGeneral("URL_API_ZeusSalud", "SISTEMA")."/HistoriaClinica/SaveHistoriaClinica"; ?>";
            console.log(guardarHC);

           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(guardarHC),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){console.log(data+"Guardo");},
                failure: function(errMsg) {
                    console.log(errMsg);
                }
            });
```

The part that doesn't ship is this **guardarHC.XmlProcedimientos = XmlProcedimientos;**

Below I show you how to put together this Array:

```
var XmlProcedimientos = new Array();
            var ingreso = <?php echo $model->getIngreso($_SESSION['estudio']); ?>;
            getJSONAjax(null,"CtrlDatosHistoria.php?operacion=getProcsFacturados&ingreso="+ingreso, function(response){
                var procedimientos = response.procedimientos;
                procedimientos.forEach(function(campos, index){
                    XmlProcedimientos[index] = {};
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].diagnostico = campos['codigoDiagnostico'];
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].servicio = String(campos['servicio']);
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].codigo = campos['codigo'];
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].nombre = campos['nombre'];
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].valor = Number(campos['valor']);
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].codigoActividad = campos['codigoActividad'];
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].fechaServicio = $("#fecha_atencion_historia").val();
                    XmlProcedimientos[index].codigoActividadDeta = campos['codigoActividadDeta'];
                });
            }, "POST", true, "");
```

By making a console.log to save it is apparently armed.

But when sending it appears empty.

Comment: it is empty because you are sending the data before the function `getJSONAjax` finishes doing whatever it is that it does. You need to have a promise and wait for the function to resolve before setting it within your data.

Comment: Hello, put the code where I build the Json inside the getJSONAjax and now if it works. But I don't understand the concept of Promise well, how is it possible to know the way to know if the getJSONAjax has finished.

Comment: That is a tough one to explain in a stackoverflow post to cover everything. I would recommend reading [about Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) on MDN.